# Quicksight - distinct count of a value while ignoring filters

Tags: count, filtering, amazon-quicksight

I need to compare an initial distinct count of values (with no filters applied) vs a distinct count of the same values after some filters have been applied.

I've searched a lot and can't find how to do this. Not sure if level aware calculation will work since I don't need to do a countOver.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in a graph, filters have the option to be applied only in some visuals:

[image: Edit filter]

[Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/add-a-filter-data-prep.html)